# Cannot clear cache in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am doing a simple "Hello World" drupal module but it doesn't work.

I have the hello_world.info.yml in `drupal/web/modules/custom/hello_world`

The modules is installed and working.

Now I added a hello_world.routing.yml with this code:

```
hello_world.hello:
  path: '/hello'
  defaults:
    _controller:
'\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::helloWorld'
  _title: 'Our first route'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

And a HelloWorldController.php in /src:

```
namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
/**
 * Controller for the salutation message.
 */
class HelloWorldController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Hello World.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function helloWorld() {
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World')
    ];
  }
}
```

When I click on "clear cache" so the routing and the controller are added, I get:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

This does not happen before I added the controller and routing.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your controller into `/src/Controller` not just `/src`.

And rename all occurrences of `helloWorld()` to `content()` and inherit docs as in [Introductory Drupal 8 routes and controllers example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example).

Comment: I am not following that tutorial, but also tried it from scratch without luck.

Comment: @prgrm – I'd bet there is typo somewhere. In your routing.yml `_controller:` and `'\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::helloWorld'` must be on the same line.

Comment: @prgrm To avoid Typos, it's always better to use https://drupalconsole.com/ to generate skeletons for module, **controller**, service, blocks etc use `drupal gc` to generate controller